# 301 Permanent Redirect in ASP.NET MVC changing url with https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, https

I am making a change in the URL from a Web Forms system to an Asp .Net MVC system. This URL is modified and then redirected, being changed to moved permanently
In HTTP environments it works correctly. However, in HTTPS environment, after redirecting, the URL is changed to HTTP. Any suggestion?
I already checked in IIS and at first I didn't find any point forcing this conversion.

```
const string status = "301 Moved Permanently";
var request = httpContext.Request;
var response = httpContext.Response;

var legacyUrl = new System.Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl).ToString();
var newUrl = "";

if (legacyUrl.ToLower().Contains("login.aspx"))
{
  newUrl = legacyUrl.ToLower().Replace("login.aspx", "Login");
  newUrl = newUrl.Replace("login", "Login");
  response.Status = status;
  response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
  response.End();
}
```

The URL is kept in HTTPS, however, after this redirection, it is converted to HTTP in some location that I could not identify.

Note: If I modify the variable:

```
newUrl = "https://google.com";
```

The redirect works correctly, sending with HTTPS.
However, by inserting the fixed URL with HTTPS for the internal path of the website, it redirects to HTTP.

Comment: First please clear your cache and try again, If it is still the same issue, you can try to use failed request tracking to see where to redirect https to http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading several articles I found the problem. In tests where there was an error, I was removing the HTTP option from bindings in IIS.
It turns out that it is necessary for operation.
However, to maintain in HTTPS environment it is necessary to use the URL Rewrite. This way it goes through HTTP and is then redirected to HTTPS.